# Scala Testing with Mock objects within objects

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, scalatest

While Testing `Called1.writeData` and mocking using the traits, control is still going to the original implementation. Need help from experts.

```
object Caller1() {
  def method1(param1:String, param2:Long) {
    val param3=param1 //Some transformation
    val param4=param2
  
    Called1.writeData(param3, param4)
  }
}

object Called1 extends Called1Trait {
  val producer = Called2.createProducer

  def writeData {
    val data = createData(param1)
    Called2.MethodA(...)
  }

  def createData(param1) {
    // Some code
  }
}

object Called2 extends Called2Trait {
  def createProducer {
    // Some code
  }

  def methodA {
    // Some code
  }

  def methodB {
    // methodA is used here 
  }
}
```

I have used mocking of the traits and using `when` and `then` to bypass the execution. Yet it is going to the methods. I have used `any()`.

```
    val CalledObject1Mock = mock[CalledObject1Trait]
    val CalledObject2Mock = mock[CalledObject2Trait]

    when(CalledObject1Mock.createProducer).thenReturn(ProducerMock)
    when(CalledObject1Mock.writeData(any(),any())).thenReturn(true)
    when(CalledObject1Mock.createData(any())).thenReturn(MockedData)

    when(CalledObject2Mock.methodA(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(true)
    when(CalledObject2Mock.methodB(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(true)

    Called1.writeData(testParam1, testParam2) // this is failing
```

We have used scala Mockito. So do not intend to use any other framework.

```
import org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuite
import org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AnyFlatSpec
import org.scalatestplus.mockito.MockitoSugar
import org.scalatest.matchers.should._

trait BaseTestSuite extends AnyFunSuite with BeforeAndAfterAll with Matchers with MockitoSugar {
```

Answer (score 0):

The current design does not allow to test it by Mock.

1. You mocked the called objects but don't use them. The original `Called1` does not know about mocked objects.
2. You should not mock a class under the testing.

To fix it I would suggest redesigning your classes this way:

```
class Caller1(called1: Called1Trait) {
  def method1(param1:String, param2:Long) {
    val param3=param1 //Some transformation
    val param4=param2
  
    called1.writeData(param3, param4)
  }
}

class Called1(called2: Called2Trait) extends Called1Trait {
  val producer = called2.createProducer

  def writeData {
    val data = createData(param1)
    called2.methodA(...)
  }

  def createData(param1) {
    // Some code
  }
}

class Called2 extends Called2Trait {
  def createProducer {
    // Some code
  }

  def methodA {
    // Some code
  }

  def methodB {
    // methodA is used here 
  }
}
```

So, assume you want to test the `Called1`. The test will look like this:

```
    val called2Mock = mock[Called2Trait]
    when(called2Mock.methodA(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(true)
    when(called2Mock.methodB(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(true)

    val called1 = new Called1(called2Mock)
    called1.writeData(testParam1, testParam2)
```

Now the `called1` knows that `called2` is mocked object and will call the mocked `methodA()`.